# ZF2 get url param and redirect on dispatch_error event

Tags: zend-framework2

I have the code to change the language of site. I would like to extend this functional. I want to make sure that the language parameter in the url is correct when I get the 404 page (or dispatch_error event).

My route example

```
'about' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/[:lang/]about',
                'constraints' => array(
                      'lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}?',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'about',
                    'lang'       => 'en',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

If url param isn't correct (example.com/e/about or exampleDotcom//about), then makes redirect to the specific page (for example, example.com/why_did_it_happen). To make this, I create a function checkRedirect and attach it to EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR . But how to get the LANG parameter from the url and then make a redirect, I don't know. I tried to do this many times, but could not. I've got - Call to a member function getParam () on a non-object. What code would I append to the checkRedirect function  to get the LANG parameter from the url and then make a redirect in this function?

My code in Module.php

```
class Module implements 
AutoloaderProviderInterface,
ConfigProviderInterface,
ViewHelperProviderInterface {

public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'initLocale'), -100);
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, array($this, 'checkRedirect'), -101);
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'preDispatch'), 100);
}

public function initLocale(MvcEvent $e) {
    $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');        
    $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Config');
    $shotLang = $e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('lang'); //or $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
    if (isset($config['languages'][$shotLang])) {
        $translator->setLocale($config['languages'][$shotLang]['locale']);
    } else {
        $lang = array_shift($config['languages']);
        $translator->setLocale($lang['locale']);
    }
}

public function checkRedirect(MvcEvent $e) {
   //code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('NAME')
```

This does work, but 'NAME', but be the name given in the routes.

```
'route'    => '/[:lang/]about',
```

However, the above route does not match the route *example.com/why_did_it_happen*

Try changing your route to

```
'route'    => '[/:lang]/about',
```

And you could always default, if a lang is not supplied, i.e.

```
$e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('lang', 'en');
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have changed route to `'route'    => '[/:lang]/about',` and add code `public function checkRedirect(MvcEvent $e) {
   $e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('lang');
}` but I still have `Call to a member functon getParam() on a non-object`...  PS `$e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('lang', 'en');` doesn't work too.